# Transformar array números en asteriscos

Tags: c++

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código que coge un array de números y los transforma en * (escribiendolos de arriba a abajo). Si el array fuese (2-4) de la forma en la que tengo el código me lo saca así:

```
    2
    *
    *
    
    4
    *
    *
    *
    *
```

Yo necesito que me lo saque de la siguiente forma:

```
2 4
* *
* *
  *
  *
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numeros[10]= {9, 4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 2, 10, 7, 6};
    int a;
    printf("\n El array de numeros es: %d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n", numeros[0],numeros[1],numeros[2],numeros[3],numeros[4],numeros[5],numeros[6],numeros[7],numeros[8],numeros[9]);

    for(int i= 0; i< 10; i++){
        for(int e= 0; e<= a; e++) {
            a= numeros[i]; 
            printf("*");
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿has probado a reemplazar el salto de línea que añades justo después de imprimir un asterisco por un espacio?

Comment: Y, ya puestos... ¿Has probado a tabular el código y a eliminar los saltos de línea innecesarios que tienes en tu código? Así conseguirías que fuese más legible y facil de leer

Comment: La variable `a` está sin inicializar al llegar al `for` la primera vez. Y ese `for` en el que la `a`, condición de finalización, va cambiando en cada iteración.... No entiendo lo que quieres hacer pero me huelo que no está bien.

Comment: ¿Has cambiado el orden en el segundo ejemplo? ¿O realmente tienen que salir así?

Comment: Hola a todos, he editado la pregunta para que os quede todo más claro, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

En tu código tienes un error al no inicializar la variable `a` antes de que el flujo del programa entre al segundo ciclo for. La siguiente línea deberías ubicarla fuera del cuerpo del ciclo anidado.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a = numeros[i];
    for (int e = 0; e <= a; e++) {
        // Imprimir
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, no vas a lograr lo que deseas con esta lógica porque tienes que imprimir en una misma línea asteriscos que corresponden a distintos valores del arreglo.

La idea sería iterar en un sentido de filas-columnas. Donde las filas irían de 0 hasta `m`, donde `m` es el valor más grande del arreglo, y las columnas serían la cantidad de elementos del arreglo.

```
int n = 10; // Cantidad de elementos del arreglo
int m; // Número mayor del arreglo 
// Se asume que ya se ha encontrado e inicializado m

for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        // Si el número en la posición j es mayor o igual que la fila + 1,
        // entonces se imprime un asterisco
        if (numeros[j] >= i + 1) {
            printf("* ");
        } else {
            printf("  ");
        }
    }
    // Cuando se termine de procesar la fila, se imprime un salto de línea
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: He probado la técnica que has sugerido y no transforma todos los números del array en asteriscos. Únicamente aparece una fila de izquierda a derecha con asteriscos y finaliza el programa.

Comment: Inicializaste el valor de la variable m?

Comment: Disculpa, soy muy novato en C++, en m, ¿lo tengo que inicializar con el valor del número mas alto del array? (En el caso de mi código 10)

Comment: Si, y pues si los valores del arreglo no se pudieran saber de antemano, necesitarías otro algoritmo para encontrar el mayor número.

Comment: Ya he inicializado m y no lo hace correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Al final ya he resuelto el problema. Añado el código final corregido.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int numeros[10] = {9, 4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 2, 10, 7, 6};

    printf("\n El array de numeros es:\n %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d %d  %d  %d\n", numeros[0], numeros[1], numeros[2], numeros[3], numeros[4], numeros[5], numeros[6], numeros[7], numeros[8], numeros[9]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (i+1 <= numeros[j]) {
                printf(" * ");
            } else {
                printf("   ");
            }
        }
      printf("\n");  
    }
}
```

Saludos y gracias a todos.